# Sort element with property: true to the top, but only one out of many

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, mongodb-atlas

My app can search through a database of resources using MongoDB's [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/). Some of these documents have the property `sponsored: true`.

I want to move **exactly one** of these sponsored entries to the top of the search results, but keep natural ordering up for the remaining ones (**no matter if sponsored or not**).

Below is my code. My idea was to make use of `addFields` **but change the logic so that it only applies to the first element that meets the condition. Is this possible?**

```
[...]

const aggregationResult = await Resource.aggregate()
    .search({
        compound: {
            must: [
                [...]
            ],
            should: [
                [...]
            ]
        }
    })
    [...]
    //only do this for the first sponsored result
    .addFields({
        selectedForSponsoredSlot: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$sponsored', true] }, true, false] }
            })
    .sort(
        {
            selectedForSponsoredSlot: -1,
            _id: 1
        }
    )
    .facet({
        results: [
            { $match: matchFilter },
            { $skip: (page - 1) * pageSize },
            { $limit: pageSize },
        ],
        totalResultCount: [
            { $match: matchFilter },
            { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
        ],
        [...]
    })
    .exec();

[...]
```

Comment: @nimrodserok Not quite the same because now I want to keep the other sponsored results and treat them like normal organic results. Do you know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:
One option is to change your `$facet` a bit:

1. You can get the `$match` out of the `$facet` since it is relevant to all pipelines.
2. instead of two pipelines, one for the results and one for the counting, we have now three: one more for `sponsored` documents only.
3. remove items that were already seen previously according to the `sposerted` item relevance score.
4. remove the item that is in the `sponserd` array from the `allDocs` array (if it is in this page).
5. `$slice` the `allDocs` array to be in the right size to complete the sponsered items to the wanted `pageSize`
6. `$project` to concatenate `sponsored` and `allDocs` docs

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {relevance: -1, _id: 1}},
  {$match: matchFilter},
  {$facet: {
      allDocs: [{$skip: (page - 1) * (pageSize - 1)}, {$limit: pageSize + 1 }],
      sposerted: [{$match: {sponsored: true}}, {$limit: 1}],
      count: [{$count: "total"}]
  }},
  {$set: {
      allDocs: {
        $slice: [
          "$allDocs",
          {$cond: [{$gte: [{$first: "$sposerted.relevance"},
                  {$first: "$allDocs.relevance"}]}, 1, 0]},
          pageSize + 1
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$set: {
      allDocs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$allDocs",
          cond: {$not: {$in: ["$$this._id", "$sposerted._id"]}}
        }
      }
  }},
  {$set: {allDocs: {$slice: ["$allDocs",  0, (pageSize - 1)]}}},
  {$project: {
      results: {
        $concatArrays: [ "$sposerted", "$allDocs"]},
        totalResultCount: {$first: "$count.total"}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CsHDNQ5c77_)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out! Will this splitting up and recombining via `$project` have a performance impact? Also, I don't need to extract the `matchFilter` for it to work, right? You can't see it in my example code but there is actually a part in the count facet that needs to have the matchFilter **not** applied.

Comment: Since you already using `$facet`, the additional performance impact should be small. No problem to use the `matchFilter` inside the `$facet`

Comment: I have trouble understanding the purpose of the `$slice` part. Doesn't `$filter` already remove the sponsored element(s) and make the resulting array the correct size?

Comment: It is removing the sponsored  element(s) from the array, but what if they were not there? Then the array is bigger than needed

Comment: Assume we want 50 results and 2 of them are sponsored. If these 2 are in the original `allDocs`, than after the `$filter` its size will be 48, and combined is 50 again. But if they are not in it, than the `$filter` will do nothing and we'll end up with a 52 items array, which is not what we want. Hence the `$slice`

Comment: How would you approach this if the sponsored slot should take pagination into account as well? I.e. on page 1, the first out of the ten results should be the sponsored item. On pages two and higher, no sponsored elements should be shown. I guess I have to do the pagination in a later step.

Comment: Also, the 2nd line `{$sort: {sponsored: -1, _id: 1}}` should be removed, right?

Comment: To me, it seems like the `$slice` call would shave off results from that page that would then be "lost". Am I mistaken?

Comment: Is the last comment regarding the current question or the new approach?

Comment: It's about this question

Comment: I left out the `slice` and it seems to work properly. I also add the sponsored result only if `page === 1`. The only "bug" is that the first page now has one more result than the other pages. And the page where the sponsored item was originally placed now has 1 less. But that doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: Updated the answer to avoid this

Comment: Will this take into account if no sponsored entry was found for that query? Otherwise, I'll just leave the result number bug. It's not a big deal.